# How to select specific columns containing certain strings/characters?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have this dataframe:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c("correct", "wrong", "wrong", "correct"),
  b = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  c = c("wrong", "wrong", "wrong", "wrong"),
  d = c(2, 2, 3, 4))

a       b c     d
correct 1 wrong 2
wrong   2 wrong 2
wrong   3 wrong 3
correct 4 wrong 4
```

and would like to select only the columns with either the strings 'correct' or 'wrong' (i.e., columns b and d in df1), such that I get this dataframe:

```
df2 <- data.frame(a = c("correct", "wrong", "wrong", "correct"),
        c = c("wrong", "wrong", "wrong", "wrong"))

        a     c
1 correct wrong
2   wrong wrong
3   wrong wrong
4 correct wrong
```

Can I use dplyr to do this? If not, what function(s) can I use to do this? The example I've given is straightforward, in that I can just do this (dplyr):

```
select(df1, a, c)
```

However, in my actual dataframe, I have about 700 variables/columns and a few hundred columns that contain the strings 'correct' or 'wrong' and I don't know the variable/column names.

Any suggestions as to how to do this quickly? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use base `R` `Filter` which will operate on each of `df1`'s columns and keep all ones satisfying the logical test in the function:

```
Filter(function(u) any(c('wrong','correct') %in% u), df1)
#        a     c
#1 correct wrong
#2   wrong wrong
#3   wrong wrong
#4 correct wrong
```

You can also use `grepl`:

```
Filter(function(u) any(grepl('wrong|correct',u)), df1)
```

Comment: I was going to do `df1[sapply(df1, function(x) any(x %in% c("correct", "wrong")))]` but this is nicer.

Comment: Didn't know there's Filter in base R! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

---- update ----- 
Thanks Colonel Beavel. What an elegant solution. I will def use `Filter` more.

I want to check a speed solution too just in case time is an important factor:

```
locator <- apply(df1, 2, function(x) grepl("correct|wrong", x))
index <- apply(locator, 2, any)
newdf <- df1[,!index]
```

I expanded your data frame to 500,000 columns:

```
dftest <- as.data.frame(replicate(500000, df1[,1]))
```

Then tested the system time for a function with `apply`, `Filter` with grepl, and `Filter` with pattern %in%:

```
f <- function() {
locator <- apply(dftest, 2, function(x) grepl("correct|wrong", x))
index <- apply(locator, 2, any)
newdf <- dftest[,!index]
}

f1 <- function() {newdf <- (Filter(function(x) any(c("wrong", "correct") %in% x), dftest))}

f2 <- function() {newdf <- Filter(function(u) any(grepl('wrong|correct',u)), dftest)}


system.time(f())
   user  system elapsed 
   24.32    0.00   24.35 
system.time(f1())
   user  system elapsed 
   2.31    0.00    2.34 
system.time(f2())
   user  system elapsed 
   8.66    0.01    8.71
```

Colonel's solution is by far the best one. It's clean and performs best. --credit @akrun for data.frame suggestion.

Comment: `dftest` is a matrix.  The `Filter` would give a vector ouput, so I am not sure the comparison is correct.  May be you need to convert the `dftest` to `data.frame` and then do the comparison.  If I convert `dftest` to `data.frame`, the system.time I got are `system.time(f())
   #user  system elapsed 
 #19.010   0.095  19.097 ; system.time(f1())
#   user  system elapsed 
  2.290   0.004   2.292 `

Comment: I also tried with `dftest` as a  `matrix`.  `system.time(f())
#   user  system elapsed 
 # 7.081   0.008   7.084 `.  Still it didn't beat the ColonelBeauvel's function.

Comment: For your function, the matrix would be better (in general, matrix is faster), but unfortunately, the `Filter` requires a data.frame to get the correct output.  It may be better to remove the initial comparisons with the `Filter` as it gives the wrong output.